# Timers are interleaved, Dashboard update event getting skipped +

Tags: vb.net

I'm working on a Windows Form Desktop application using VB.Net and there is one form which acts as a dashboard having 3 timers where each timer is responsible for its own specific part of the dashboard. The issue is with one timer where that timer should call a user-defined Sub which updates the database, but sometimes the timer gets skipped or ignored, which results in missing dashboard information. I tried using sleep and then Async Await to fix the problem, but the behavior is still the same.
the Idea behind this code is receiving numbers for a queuing system and insert them inside a queue then apply some behavior on the peek record like blinking and beep sound then change Its state using the Call sub that not called well inside the timer.

here is a a similar code inside that timer.

```
Private Sub timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    If myQueue.Count > 0 Then
        label1.Text = myQueue.Peek().ToString()
        x -= 1

        If x = 10 Then
            label1.Visible = False
        End If

        If x = 8 Then
            label1.Visible = True
        End If

        If x = 6 Then
            label1.Visible = False
        End If

        If x = 4 Then
            label1.Visible = True
        End If

        If x = 2 Then
            label1.Visible = False
        End If

        If x = 0 Then
            label1.Visible = True
            x = 12
            myQueue.Dequeue()
            Call Sub1(Par1)
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What is `x`? Have you monitored the queue to check the `Count` when it is skipped? Also, consider using a `Select Case` block which will make the intent more obvious and easier to maintain.

Comment: x is a simple counter that = 12 in the beginning and is for control blinking of the text only.